# Appearance of room-temperature strange matter

Tags: visible-light, exotic-matter

Assuming [strange matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet) is stable at zero pressure, how might a chunk of room-temperature strange matter look? Assume it's in a zero-gravity vacuum. Would it be transparent or opaque? Would it appear metallic? Black? White? Colored?

Comment: If you have read the reference you supply, you should understand that the appearance will depend on the particular model of strangelet: charged? neutral? In general it should be opaque because quarks are charged and even a neutral strangelet will not be penetrable by electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @annav - Thanks. It looks like I should have done more research.